# fixing IE7 float inside float bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

in ie7 if you put a floated element inside a floated element to the same side
the inside element just pushed far away outside the container element to the direction of the float.

consider this code

```
<div style="float: right">
<div style="float: right">
    some text
</div></div>
```

any solution for this bug??

Comment: Have you tried setting a width for each element?

Comment: i can't, the width is unknown..

Comment: if you dont set a width then they will be the same size and floating makes no sense. the inner one has to have a width

Comment: why? its a set of elements with different widths, i don't want to limit my width. there's got to be another way...

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the given code in ie7, the text "some text" went to the right end only.
U can try with padding or margin.

Comment: i didn't quite understood you'r answer i"m afraid, tho one thing i notes is that the bug only triggered when the HTML tag is set to dir="rtl"